# automatically Copy files to entire client pc on local network

Tags: batch-file, networking, vbscript, command-prompt

i have some problem here,i have some file in my local server,a.pl,b.pl,c.pl
i need to copy it automatically to C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\ in entire client pc on my local server network (100 PC) 
I  want this to run from a simple script, so maybe VBS or perhaps a batch file would be best. But i'm open to suggestions.

thanks and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List turned on computers

```
for /f "skip=3 delims=\" %%A in ('net view ^| findstr /v /C:"The command completed successfully"') do Echo %%A >> "%userprofile%\desktop\computerlist.txt"
```

Copy a file

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%userprofile%\desktop\computerlist.txt") do echo copy C:\localfile \\%%A\C$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\
```